# Hibernate Query By Example not working as expected

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

everyone.

Sorry for some english mistakes.

I am using Vaadin to build a front-end search interface for some search tasks.

In front-end I have only one text field called "telefone" that should fill three fields in my entity bean (telefone1, telefone2 and telefone3), because the telephone number provided by user can be found in any "telefone" field. See the code below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public List<Fornecedor> executaPesquisaAvancadaDeFornecedores(Fornecedor fornecedor) {
    Map<Integer, Fornecedor> fornecedoresMap = new HashMap<Integer, Fornecedor>();

    if(fornecedor.getTelefone1() != null) fornecedor.setTelefone1("%" + fornecedor.getTelefone1() + "%");
    fornecedor.setTelefone2(fornecedor.getTelefone1());
    fornecedor.setTelefone3(fornecedor.getTelefone1());

    Example exampleFornecedor = Example.create(fornecedor).enableLike(MatchMode.ANYWHERE).ignoreCase();

    Criteria criteria = super.getSession().createCriteria(Fornecedor.class, "fornecedor").add(exampleFornecedor);

    List<Fornecedor> fornecedores = criteria.list();
    for(Fornecedor f : fornecedores) {
        fornecedoresMap.put(f.getId(), f);
    }

    return new ArrayList<Fornecedor>(fornecedoresMap.values());
}
```

In this case, there is no result provided by criteria.list() method. But if I remove "telefone2" and "telefone3" setters, like this...

```
if(fornecedor.getTelefone1() != null) fornecedor.setTelefone1("%" + fornecedor.getTelefone1() + "%");
```

... the criteria and the QBE returns the result correctly, but only if the telephone provided is saved in "telefone1" field.

My question is why this occurs? AFAIK, Hibernate Query By Example matches the results based on the given search fields filled, ignoring null attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are building a condition (with s = '%' + entered search string + '%'):

```
(telefone1 LIKE s) AND (telefone2 LIKE s) AND (telefone3 LIKE s)
```

I guess that you really want

```
(telefone1 LIKE s) OR (telefone2 LIKE s) OR (telefone3 LIKE s)
```

If that is true you can't use query by example which always produces and-connected conditions. Try to use HQL or the criteria API instead.